# Where can I buy Framesaver in Canada?

Tags: maintenance, regional, rust, canada

My LBS has told me they're unable to order [Framesaver](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/tools/chain-lubricant/product/frame-saver-10220) due to difficulties shipping aerosol canisters across the border. Are there any reputable retailers (either online or in the Greater Toronto Area) who've dealt with the hassle and have Framesaver available for sale within Canada?

Comment: Doesn't WD40 do the same thing?

Comment: @mgb: I think WD40 evaporates and leaves nothing behind

Comment: Never needed to coat the inside of a frame, WD40 is useful to get any water out. I suppose car wax could work?

Comment: @mgb accidental upvote on comment... Meant to agree with freiheit. WD40 does *not* leave any protective coating behind. I was hoping for something to coat and protect since I have reasonably harsh Canadian weather to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

You can get it from Niagra Cycle Works via Amazon.com. Not quite the great TO area but not too far either.

[http://www.amazon.com/T-9-Rust-Protectant-Ounce-Spray/dp/B001447PEK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1298302015&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001447PEK)

Answer (score 2):

Framesaver is really hard to get, also sucks to breathe and get on the skin, I would use linseed oil instead, apply it pretty much the same, break frame down squirts some down all tubes and rotate bike all around for an even coating, the linseed will cake on the steel and leave a residue that's harmless to steels but will protect from oxide. Linseed oil can be purchased at hardware stores for about 10 bucks a litre which will do a few frames

Answer (score 1):

No idea how to get Framesaver into Canada, but there are some alternatives.

- A classic alternative to Framesaver is [Linseed oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linseed_oil). It's a liquid oil that slowly hardens. Used to be common as a wood varnish, so you might find it at a hardware or furniture store. If you go this route, be careful with rags, since a rag soaked in linseed oil can spontaneously combust.
- [Boeshield T-9](http://boeshield.com/features-benefits/bicycles/) or another paraffin based chain lube should work reasonably well. It's basically waxy stuff in a solvent that leaves the waxy stuff behind.
- As [ChrisW](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/1097/chrisw) suggests: check out an auto store. They may have a rust-inhibiting product that would work, too.

Comment: "hardware or furniture store" - Alternatively maybe a car/automobile shop would sell a rust-inhibiting product, for steel.